# Eclipse browser not showing mark tags

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using the widget class to show a browser window in eclipse. Part of my html code includes the  tag. In a regular browser (chrome/firefox) I see the text highlighted in yellow, but in eclipse the mark is not doing anything.

I tried different browser under preferences : use internal web browser (tried the default/ firefox and even IE). Any suggestions on how to make it pick that tag?

Comment: old version of eclipse does not support HTML5 so make sure that you are using new version of eclipse

Comment: I am using 4.3.2, it also seems like the import of my css is not working well in eclipse

Comment: I am saying this because I replaced the mark with a span with class="markClass" with background-color:yellow, and it is not working.
If I do however write my code as <span style=background-color:yellow> it does work